# $cordovaFileTransfer.download is not a function ionic v1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm getting this error

$cordovaFileTransfer.download is not a function

my code is this

```
app.controller('GalleryCtrl', ['$scope', '$cordovaFileTransfer', function($scope, $cordovaFileTransfer) {
$scope.testFileDownload = function () {

    var url = "http://www.gajotres.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo_radni.png";
    var filename = url.split("/").pop();
    var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
    alert(targetPath);

    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, {}, true).then(function (result) {
        alert('Success!');
    }, function (error) {
        alert('Error!');
    }, function (progress) {
        // PROGRESS HANDLING GOES HERE
    });
  };

}])
```

In my app js I have defined ngCordova

Comment: Did you install it with the CLI? cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Answer (score 0):

install this plugin: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer

then use this code. I hope it will meet your requirement

```
app.controller('GalleryCtrl', ['$scope', '$cordovaFileTransfer', function($scope, $cordovaFileTransfer) {
  $scope.testFileDownload = function() {

        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var url = "http://www.gajotres.net/wpcontent/uploads/2015/04/logo_radni.png";
        var uri = encodeURI(url);
        var filename = url.split("/").pop();
        var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
        alert(targetPath);

        fileTransfer.download(uri, targetPath, function(entry) {
          alert('Success!');
          // PROGRESS HANDLING GOES HERE
        },
        function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));

        },
        false, {
            headers : {
                "Authorization" :"BasicdGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
                }
        });
    };

}])
```